# Searching through all subfolders when using Resources.Load in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to have Resources.Load(name, type) search for a fitting asset not just in the base Resources folder / a specified subfolder, but instead the full subfolder structure under Resources?

Example folder structure of

```
Resources
  - Subfolder
    - image.png
```

I would like something like Resources.Load("image", typeof(Texture2D)) to return the image without the user having to specify "Subfolder/image".

I know it's ugly, but it's supposed to be a "drop it in your bashed together project without worrying about your folder structure"-type utility script and I won't know the subfolder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to change the `Resouces.Load()` static method functionality, it's Unity Internal. However, you can write your own custom class that does your desired functionality. The code needs to find all the directories inside the `Resources` folder and search for the file. Let's call the class `ResourcesExtension`

```
public class ResourcesExtension
{
    public static string ResourcesPath = Application.dataPath+"/Resources";

    public static UnityEngine.Object Load(string resourceName, System.Type systemTypeInstance) 
    {
    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(ResourcesPath,"*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var item in directories)
    {
        string itemPath = item.Substring(ResourcesPath.Length+1);
        UnityEngine.Object result = Resources.Load(itemPath+"\\"+resourceName,systemTypeInstance);
        if(result!=null)
            return result;
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is calling the static method.

```
ResourcesExtension.Load("image", typeof(Texture2D))
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's easy enough to implement, I just hoped that maybe there is a prebuilt (optimized) option available, but seems I'll have to do it this way.

Comment: Just a note that I don't think this will work in a build - only in editor. I haven't tried it so take it as a possibility only - I've read about this in other threads, so test it in your build before you get heavily into using it.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer only works in the editor context, and doesn't work after building the game. The resources folder is packed when building your game, and will no longer be a file hierarchy you can loop through with Directory.GetDirectories. The only way to get this to work is to save all file paths while still in the editor context, and use this file hierarchy to load the assets at runtime. In my project I used the following code to add a button to the component that uses the assets in the resources folder, named CharacterGen. When this button is clicked, all png files in all subfolders in the Resources folder are saved to the public attribute named filePaths that CharacterGen has.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(CharacterGen))]
public class RefreshCharacterList : Editor
{
    CharacterGen charGen;
    public void OnEnable()
    {
        charGen = (CharacterGen)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Load resource paths"))
        {
            List<String> paths = new List<string>();
            LoadPathsRecursive("", ref paths);
            charGen.filePaths = paths;
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(charGen); //original post didn't have this line, but this is needed to make sure your changes are saved. 
    
        }
    }


    void LoadPathsRecursive(string path, ref List<string> paths)
    {
        var fullPath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/" + path;
        Debug.Log("fullPath: " + fullPath);
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
        foreach(var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (file.Name.Contains(".PNG") && !file.Name.Contains(".meta"))
            {
                paths.Add(path + "/" + file.Name.Replace(".PNG", ""));
            }
        }
      
        foreach (var dir in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            LoadPathsRecursive(path + "/" + dir.Name, ref paths);
        }
    }

}
```

In CharacterGen I later evoke Resources.Load, using the paths that were saved when clicking the button.

```
foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
{
   var loadedSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(filePath);
   //Do something with loadedSprite
}
```

Edit: I failed to mention an important detail in my original post. the filePaths is a Monobehaviour field, and I marked it with [SerializeField] (alternatively it could be marked as public) so that unity actually serializes the values of this field and includes it in the build.

Comment: Can you explain your solution better ? In my case I need to store sprites inside a dictionary. I applied your solution to my project but if I click on my custom button in order to load sprites into the dictionary and then go to play mode, this results null. This happens also if I try to build.  It seems like when entering in play mode or building the project all scripts are reinitialized. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Oh I see I missed an important detail in my post. *filePaths* should be a MonoBehaviour field marked with [SerializeField] (or alternatively it should be a public), so that unity serializes the values added to that field. Also, it should be supported as serializable. A dictionary isn't serializable by default by Unity so you could try saving all paths as a list, and then build up a dictionary at runtime (not sure if this is feasible for your exact situation).

Comment: I tried with a list but this doesn't resolve the issue. When clicking custom button in inspector, list in my component is correctly filled with my values but when entering in play mode these values disappears and list is empty.  I am using Unity 2021.3.3f1, could be this version the problem ?

Comment: Oh I think I know what's going on. So you're making a change in the editor, but the editor isn't marked as dirty, so your change isn't saved. 

You should add this line inside the if clause in OnInspectorGUI: 
EditorUtility.SetDirty(gameObject)
gameObject should be the object containing the list. 

This marks the scene as dirty, and you'll be prompted to save your changes after clicking the button.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to find all Object of a type and return as a List.
it Emad code Edited a bit.

```
private List<T> FindAllObject<T>()
{
    List<T> tmp = new List<T>();
    string ResourcesPath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources";
    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(ResourcesPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string item in directories)
    {
        string itemPath = item.Substring(ResourcesPath.Length + 1);
        T[] reasult = Resources.LoadAll(itemPath, typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToArray();

        foreach (T x in reasult)
        {
            if (!tmp.Contains(x))
            {
                tmp.Add(x);
            }
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

To use it.

```
List<MyClass> myClasses = FindAllObject<MyClass>();
```